# Accessing C# List variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#

C#

```
public List<double> Coordinatesx = new List<Double>();
    public List<double> Coordinatesy = new List<Double>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TRY"].ConnectionString);
        string query = "select x,y from Addresses";
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
        SqlDataReader id = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(id.Read())
        {
            Coordinatesx.Add(Convert.ToDouble(id[0]));
            Coordinatesy.Add(Convert.ToDouble(id[1]));
         }
         cnn.Close();

   }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function calculateinside()
    {

         for (var j = 0; j < <%=Coordinatesx.Count%>; j++) {
             var point = new google.maps.LatLng(<%=Coordinatesx%>[j],<%=Coordinatesy%>[j]);
             if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point,poly)){
                 marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({

                     position: point,
                     map: map,
                     icon: 'images/point2.png',

                 });
             }
      }

    }   }
```

I am trying to take variables from c# to javascript, I have tried that code but there is an error.

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(<%=Coordinatesx%>[j],<%=Coordinatesy%>[j]);
```

How can I access each value of Coordinatesx and Coordinatesy list?

Comment: Do the *for* loop in C# too. You can't mix client-side and server-side code like that

Comment: But I have to take all coordinates from database to javascript, Is there different way?

Comment: Yup, `new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Coordinatesx)` will give you a javascript array

Comment: Then, how I will reach it from javascript code?

Comment: `var Coordinatesx = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Coordinatesx) %>. for(var i=0; i<Coordinatesx.length; i++) { console.log(Coordinatesx[i]); }`

Comment: I have 972.000 coordinates in database, I have tried that code part but there is maxJsonLength error, I have edited web.config file as

system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>

Again I have the same error, I have tried take coordinates from javascript but I heard that it has secury gap, Is there any best way for taking huge coordinates from database?

Comment: 972.000 coordinates? You're going to have **a lot** of trouble plotting those on a Google Map. Narrow it down

Comment: I won't plot all, I am trying to find coordinates inside of polygon which is defined by user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must generate the arrays in the javascript code:

```
function calculateinside()
{
     var Coordinatesx = [<%=string.Join(",", Coordinatesx)%>];
     var Coordinatesy = [<%=string.Join(",", Coordinatesy)%>];
     for (var j = 0; j < Coordinatesx.lenght; j++) {
         var point = new google.maps.LatLng(Coordinatesx[j],Coordinatesy[j]);
         if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point,poly)){
             marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({

                 position: point,
                 map: map,
                 icon: 'images/point2.png',

             });
         }
     }
}
```

if `Coordinatesx = {1,2}` and `Coordinatesy = {5,7}` in server-side code, it will generate the javascript like this:

```
function calculateinside()
{
     var Coordinatesx = [1,2];
     var Coordinatesy = [5,7];
     for (var j = 0; j < Coordinatesx.lenght; j++) {
         var point = new google.maps.LatLng(Coordinatesx[j],Coordinatesy[j]);
         if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point,poly)){
             marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({

                 position: point,
                 map: map,
                 icon: 'images/point2.png',

             });
         }
     }
}
```

You can see this, by viewing the page's html source.

Comment: I have tried that but It takes a long time because i have 672.000 coordinates and browser does not respond after a while

Comment: This is another issue, you can open new question for it.